# JavaSets from a File

Tags: java, set

I have a file that looks like this:

```
A 5
1
2
4
B 3
3
7
12
```

I need to make the the numbers after A into a set and B into a set. Here's my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("sets.dat"));

        while(in.hasNextLine()){

            String setNum = in.next();
            char whichSet = setNum.charAt(0);

            System.out.println(setNum);
            Set setOne = new HashSet();
            Set setTwo = new HashSet();         

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Should I use a `switch` statement?. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: `in.hasNextLine()` is not valid test for `in.next()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a `Map<String,Set<Integer>>` where the key of the map is the name of the set.  When you get a word, create a new Set to add numbers to, when you get a number, add it to the set.